Top n filter based on latest date power bi
enter image description hereI can show the top 5 products based on the revenue of the latest date over the last few weeks in Matrix (Power BI). Unfortunately, it cannot display in the line Chart.
Please advise how can I show the top 5 products based on the revenue of the latest date over the last few weeks in Line Chart (Power BI) which same as Matrix.

pls provide some sample  data and expected output

kindly click 'enter image description here ' to view the Matrix and chart

still not clear about the request. could you pls proivde the sample data.? How many tables do you have? what't the expected chart that you want?

Product Rank 5/19/2024 5/26/2024 6/2/2024
A 4 4 4
B 2 3 1
C 5 7 3
D 10 8 5
E 6 5 2
This is the Matrix for top 5 product. When I show in the Line chart, it was showing the top 5 products for every week differently. I want the line chart show the product A to E for every week ranking.
